# How to get the following column in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am working with a dataframe that has some dates and times, particularly I am working with the following two columns:

```
print(df[['service_window_start','delivery_window_start']])

       service_window_start delivery_window_start
0       1900-01-01 09:00:00                   NaT
1       1900-01-01 09:00:00                   NaT
2       1900-01-01 09:00:00                   NaT
.
. 
.
22      1900-01-01 09:00:00   1900-01-01 10:45:00
23      1900-01-01 09:00:00   1900-01-01 11:15:00
24      1900-01-01 09:00:00                   NaT
25      1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 15:30:00
26      1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 15:15:00
27      1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 16:45:00
28      1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 15:00:00
29      1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 16:00:00
```

I would like to get a new column called 'delay_class', the idea is to check the difference between

```
df['service_window_start']
```

and

```
df['delivery_window_start']
```

from these two columns I would like to build my new column called 'delay class' as follows:

```
if df['delivery_window_start']-df['service_window_start'] <= 15 minutes -> A
if df['delivery_window_start']-df['service_window_start'] > 15 minutes <= 60 minutes -> B
if df['delivery_window_start']-df['service_window_start'] > 60 minutes -> C
```

I am not sure how to compute this new column I tried fist changing the type of my columns as follows:

```
df['service_window_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.service_window_start)
df['delivery_window_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.delivery_window_start)
```

and then I computed the column called delay:

```
df['delay'] = df['delivery_window_start']-df['service_window_start']
```

however this gave the following output:

```
282501            00:30:00
282502            02:45:00
282503            03:45:00
282504            05:45:00
282505            03:00:00
282506            03:45:00
282507            04:30:00
282508   -1 days +23:45:00
282509            00:30:00
282510            05:30:00
282511   -1 days +23:45:00
282512            00:30:00
```

That contains the difference with days I dont want that I just want to be focus in the minutes and to get this new column called 'delay_class' something like to:

```
print(df['delay class'])

    A
    B
    A
    C
    A
```

with the ranges that I explained above I just want to create a new column with this criteria and labels so I really appreciate support to overcome this task,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Getting the delay_class

Compute the time delay as you have done.

Then, `delay_class` can be computed from function like this. The difference of two `pandas.Timestamp` objects yields a `pandas.Timedelta` object:

```
from pandas import Timedelta, NaT

def delay_class(delay=NaT):
    if delay is NaT:
        return 'A'
        # assuming a null delay means 0, modify above line if needed.
    if delay <= Timedelta(minutes=15)
        return 'A'
    if delay > Timedelta(minutes=15) and delay <= Timedelta(minutes=60):
        return 'B'
    if delay > Timedelta(minutes=60):
        return 'C'
```

apply this function to create a new column

```
df['delay class'] = df.delay.apply(delay_class)
```

#### Cleaning up the data

Investigate the rows where the delay is negative.

```
df_bad = df[df.delay < Timedelta(0)]
```

either work with only the *good* data (negate the filter condition above) or modify the bad data, (for example, set them to 0)

Comment: small typo on my part, it should be import `Timedelta`

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the support, this was really helpul